# How to share an Apps Script that is made for a specific spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So my Google Apps Script is slightly different from other Sheets add-on.

Right now I have a spreadsheet and an Apps Script made specifically for this spreadsheet (the Apps Script populates data based on the structure of this spreadsheet). There are 2 functions in that Apps Script. One will run when users click a button and one will run when a specific range of cells are changed.

My plan is to have my customers make a copy of that spreadsheet and be able to use my Apps Script by either clicking the button or changing the values of some cells.

Since my Apps Script requires some sensitive scopes, I have submitted an OAuth App verification request and my request has been granted. However I am not sure how to make my Apps Script available for other users. I have tried 2 things but none of them works:

1/ I make a copy of the above spreadsheet using another Google account. However, when I click the button, it still says the app is unverified and shows a warning. I think the reason is that when I click that button in the copied spreadsheet, it does not run my verified original Apps Script but a copied version of the original script which is linked to my original spreadsheet.

2/ I tried to submit my Apps Script as a Sheets add-on in Google Workplace Marketplace but since my add-on can only work on my particular spreadsheet, they say that: "Add-on provides all the tools needed to complete its workflow and proposed functionality. For example: if the Add-on needs an specific format or design of the sheet then the Add-on should provide a function to create it."

Really appreciate any advice on how to make my Apps Script available to everyone. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After pondering your scenario I get that you have a Sheet (with an embedded Apps Script) and your goal is to share that Sheet (including copies of the script) with some users. The easier solution is to share that project with those users. You can visit the guide about [collaborating with other developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/collaborating) to dig deeper in this topic. As an alternative you could clone the Sheet (by using `File > Make a copy`) and then [make someone else the owner of your file](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494892). Please ask me any additional doubt.

---

## UPDATE

I want to update my answer with an additional solution. You could [create a script as a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app) based on a `doGet(e)` that shows the content of the file. Sharing that web app with the desired users would allow them to see the file contents. Please don't hesitate to ask me any additional questions about this approach.

Comment: Hi there @VII! If this or any answer has helped you to solve your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: @VII I just updated my answer to add an additional solution to your question. Please take a look and let me know about the results.